# linkAndRetrieveData not working with Facebook for Firebase Authentication in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

First I am calling -

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: self)
```

On success getting credential -

```
let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
```

Then passing the credential to linkAndRetrieveData -

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.linkAndRetrieveData(with: credential)
```

Getting this error, which says “MISSING_ID_TOKEN” -

```
{
    FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey = "ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 \"(null)\" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={\n    code = 400;\n    message = \"MISSING_ID_TOKEN\";\n    status = \"INVALID_ARGUMENT\";\n}}";
    "error_name" = "ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR";
}
```

It works fine with -

```
Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be fix soon with Firebase Authentication version 5.4.1. See the issue below:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2522